# Is there a way to use a model generated by lm() on a different set of data?

Tags: r, lm

I have produced a linear model using the lm() function in R- for example,

```
lm.cars = lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp)
```

This outputs the following:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    mtcars$hp  
   30.09886     -0.06823
```

I am now in a situation where I would like to use the function defined by this model (y = -0.07x + 30.1) on a different set of data (I have different data where this makes more sense to do, but the idea is the same). So, I have a different set of x values and I want to use the function I get from a lm fit to predict the y values.
I am wondering if there is a better way to do this than reading out all the parameters manually and defining a function with them. I have quite a number of different linear models with many parameters, and this seems a little tedious. Is there a built in function that can do this for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `predict`. Importantly, your new data set has to have the same column names as in the original data set. In this case, it means that you have to create a data frame with an `hp` column:

```
my_model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
my_new_data <- data.frame(hp = runif(n=10, 50, 300))
predict(my_model, my_new_data)
```

**Output**

```
> predict(my_model, my_new_data)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
22.40625 19.90452 12.62276 14.01068 18.85295 22.92663 20.56899 24.95091 
       9       10 
25.68709 18.39930
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lm.cars <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$hp)

#New dummy data
NDummy <- mtcars
NDummy$Predict <- predict(lm.cars,NDummy)

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  Predict
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 22.59375
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 22.59375
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 23.75363
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 22.59375
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 18.15891
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 22.93489
```

With `predict()` you can use the model. Just take care of the names of variables in new data. Here I included a head of dummy data.